# Show that $h(r)$ satisfies the ODE $rh'' + h'(1+ (h')^2)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x,y)$ $=$ $h( \sqrt({x^2+y^2}))$ be a solution for the minimal surface equation.

(a) Show that $h(r)$ is a solution for the following ODE:

$rh'' + h'(1+ (h')^2)=0$

(b) What is the general solution of the equation of part (a)?

I really can't even start, I know I should put my work here, but I actually don't have any work :(.. This in NOT a homework, just I'm trying to study PDE for an exam. Help me!

Comment: Can you write the minimal surface equation in polar coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{h'(1+(h')^2)}h''+\frac{1}{r}&=0\\
\Rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{h'}-\frac{h'}{1+(h')^2}\right)h''+\frac{1}{r}&=0
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrate the above equation from $0$ to $r$,
$$
\ln h'-\frac{1}{2}\ln (1+(h')^2)+\ln r= C
$$
So
$$
\frac{h'}{\sqrt{1+(h')^2}}=\frac{C'}{r}
$$
I think you can do the rest part.